# How to parameterise a SQL REVOKE command

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sqldatasource

How can I parameterise a SQL `REVOKE` command?

```
DECLARE @ViewName nvarchar = 'MyViewName'
DECLARE @UserRole nvarchar = 'MyRoleName'

REVOKE SELECT ON [@ViewName] TO [@UserRole]
```

Outputs the following error:

```
Cannot find the object '@ViewName', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.`
```

Do I need to use Dynamic SQL to solve this or is there another way?

My actual Use Case is in ASP.NET `SqlDataClient` and the code is being generated, so I have limited control over it. The code being sent to SQL (sniffed by SQL Profiler) is:

```
exec sp_executesql N'REVOKE SELECT ON [@ViewName] TO [@UserRole]',N'@ViewName nvarchar(24),@UserRole nvarchar(12)',@ViewName=N'MyViewName',@UserRole=N'MyUserRole'
```

Comment: You have to use dynamic sql.

Comment: Because `GRANT` and `REVOKE` require considerable permissions themselves, it's usually attractive to do this in a stored procedure that builds the dynamic SQL and can execute the commands under a different credential. That way you can selectively assign the right to `REVOKE` by controlling access to the stored procedure, add auditing if this ever becomes a requirement, and last but not least you can keep using parameters.

Comment: @JeroenMostert that sounds like the right answer. If you put it as an answer and add a small example then I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `GRANT` and `REVOKE` require considerable permissions themselves, it's usually attractive to do this in a stored procedure that builds the dynamic SQL and can execute the commands under a different credential. That way you can selectively assign the right to `REVOKE` by controlling access to the stored procedure, add auditing if this ever becomes a requirement, and last but not least you can keep using parameters.

In this case:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.RevokeSelect(@ObjectName NVARCHAR(128), @RoleName NVARCHAR(128)) 
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SELECT @SQL = REPLACE(REPLACE(
        N'REVOKE SELECT ON @ObjectName TO @RoleName;',
        '@ObjectName', QUOTENAME(@ObjectName)),
        '@RoleName', QUOTENAME(@RoleName))
    ;
    -- For debugging
    --PRINT @SQL
    EXEC (@SQL)
END;
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.RevokeSelect TO [application_login];
```

Thanks to `EXECUTE AS OWNER`, the `[application_login]` account needs no additional permissions; it can `REVOKE SELECT` on any object in the database through the stored procedure. This can be exactly what you want, but if it's not, you should remove `EXECUTE AS OWNER` and grant individual `CONTROL` permission on the objects (but this, of course, allows lots of other operations as well).

Take care that a procedure that performs dynamic SQL needs careful review to ensure it's not susceptible to SQL injection, just like anything else that uses dynamic SQL. Obviously this is even more important if the procedure uses `EXECUTE AS OWNER`, since it could do anything. In this case, applying `QUOTENAME` to both parameters takes care of that.

Last but not least, while `EXECUTE AS OWNER` is simple and convenient, it will fail if the database owner is not an account but a group. In this case, if you want to delegate permissions, you'll have to create a proxy account for use in `EXECUTE AS` or sign the stored procedure with a certificate. You may want to do this anyway if developers can't be trusted with the power of `EXECUTE AS OWNER`. That goes beyond the scope of this answer, but Erland Sommerskog has an [excellent writeup](http://sommarskog.se/grantperm.html) on this topic.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to expand your comment into a full answer. Excellent!

Comment: is it also possible to parameterise the `SELECT`? i.e. `REVOKE @Permission ON @ObjectName TO @RoleName`. When I try to do this I get an error *incorrect syntax near 'SELECT'*. I'm trying to execute from a SqlDataSource which generates the following SQL (captured by SQL Profiler): `exec revokeRolePermission @Permission=N'SELECT',@RoleName=N'MyRoleName',@ObjectName=N'MyViewName'`

Comment: @Adam: You can use textual replacement, just as done with the other two parameters. Add another `REPLACE(`. Note that doing this also allows nonsensical invocations like `REVOKE BANANA`; if this is an issue you may want the stored procedure to just check the arguments (`IF @Permission = 'SELECT' THEN ...`).

Comment: I did that, but I realise my mistake now - I had the `@Permission` wrapped in the QUOTENAME function also and this was causing the error as it was parsing out as `[SELECT]` instead of `SELECT`. Easy to spot once the debug line is enabled - thanks!

Comment: @Adam: make *sure* to *check* the parameter (`IF @Permission NOT IN ('SELECT', 'GRANT') BEGIN; RAISERROR(...); RETURN;`) because you open yourself up to SQL injection with this new string that cannot be escaped (for example, `@Permission=N'REVOKE ALL ON X TO dbo; DROP TABLE MyImportantTable; --`' will happily construct a very bad statement). While this probably can't happen in your application as written, it is still good practice to prevent it entirely in the stored procedure. Even better, consider just having two separate procedures for this, as the set of things to do is very limited.

Comment: For `GRANT`, read something else, of course (you can't `REVOKE GRANT`). If we're talking views, it's hard to see why you'd ever need to grant or revoke anything else but `SELECT` permission. If you're extending this to other objects and permissions, take care that you don't accidentally create a security nightmare that can grant anyone any permission on anything, as this is very easy to exploit. (Revoking is slightly less risky, obviously.) Preventing injection is necessary in all cases.

Comment: Thanks for the additional notes on security. I've taken this into account. The system will only GRANT SELECT to SQL Views, but will be able to REVOKE on other objects (e.g. EXECUTE on a stored procedure). I'll implenent your SQL injection recommendations and then I'd say I'm covered. Thanks again!